# Accessing specific UID in array

Tags: python, database, mongodb

I got the following problem. I'm trying to pull the specific field, in the "warnings" array, which has the given UID. I can't seem to figure out why it's not working.

The output (Everything prints out successfully): [https://i.imgur.com/ZslJ0rV.png\](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsgPZ.png)
My MongoDB structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsCqS.png

```py
client = pymongo.MongoClient("")
database = client["LateNight"]
ModlogsCollection = database["modlogs"]



theUID = "63TF-lYv0-72m7-9f4I"
theGuild = 1063516188988153896



all_mod_docs = ModlogsCollection.find({"_id": str(theGuild)})
all_uids = []



for doc in all_mod_docs:
    doc_keys = [key for key in doc.keys() if key != "_id"]
    for key in doc_keys:
        sub_doc = doc[key]

        if warnings := sub_doc.get("warnings"):
            for warning in warnings:
                if warning["UID"] == theUID:
                    print(warning)
                    print("Warning")
                    result = ModlogsCollection.update_one(
                        {"_id": str(theGuild)},
                        {"$pull": {
                            "warnings": {"UID": theUID}
                        }}
                    )
                    print(result)
                    print(result.modified_count)
```

Comment: This is a similar Question with answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32017129/16766570

Answer (score 0):

as you yourself said you try to "extract the specific field, in the warnings **table** that has the UID given". Before recovering the UID value you must specify the index 0. Afterwards you get a dictionary that will have the keys:
moderator, reason, time and UID